# How repeat fade and animate using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does my code not work on this page? I get this error message, what does it mean? The code runs normally in Visual Studio Code.

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 56,
  "colno": 10
}
```

I run this code and it works, but when `$(".box3").click`, `$(".box1")` does not fade in and animate, it is directly shown in the window. After other `$(".box2")` and `$(".box3")` have some problems in the second time.

Could it be that fadeIn and animate only run one time? I it want to run more times but still have the fadeIn, fadeOut and animate effect.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box2,.box3").hide();

  $(".box1").click(function() {
    $(".box1").animate({
      left: "1200px"
    }, 1000).fadeOut();
    $(".box2").fadeIn();
  });

  $(".box2").click(function() {
    $(".box2").animate({
      left: "1200px"
    }, 1000).fadeOut();
    $(".box3").fadeIn();
  });

  $(".box3").click(function() {
    $(".box3").animate({
      left: "1200px"
    }, 1000).fadeOut();
    $(".box1").fadeIn();
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(2, 149, 246);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(22, 187, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you where the code works absolutely fine. Judging by the error, you probably put a `<script>` tag in the JS window.

Comment: thanks a lot .  I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been know answer,change fadeOut() properties.

form

```
.fadeOut()
```

become above

```
.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                        $(this).removeAttr("style")
                    });
```

The cube click can loop animate move.

```js
$(function () {
        $(".box2,.box3").hide();

        $(".box1").click(function () {
            $(".box1").animate({
                left: "1200px"
            }, 1000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("style")
            });
            $(".box2").fadeIn();
        });

        $(".box2").click(function () {
            $(".box2").animate({
                left: "1200px"
            }, 1000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("style")
            });
            $(".box3").fadeIn();
        });

        $(".box3").click(function () {
            $(".box3").animate({
                left: "1200px"
            }, 1000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("style")
            });
            $(".box1").fadeIn();
        });
    })
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(2, 149, 246);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(22, 187, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```